# Extra whitespace

Tags: php, codeigniter, whitespace

I'm getting extra space at the beginning of page ( output ),
the thing is that I didn't edit any file, I just uploaded the codeigniter framework to my server, and in the welcome page I get that space, but in localhost I don't get it. I changed all files to utf8, checked if there is any space before  ( there is no ?> )

Did someone had to deal with this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

These might help your questions:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/141220/
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/113265/

Comment: Hi, thanks , but i just resolved the problem, it seem that there was a file encoded in UTF-8 while other files are ANSI, the strange thing is codeigniter user guide recommend to save files as UTF-8
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file_format

Answer (score 0):

Check any models you are calling from your controller. I found that one of my models had extra white space at the bottom, which was causing extra lines at the top of my view.

Answer (score 0):

Encode in UTF-8 **without BOM**. (notepad++ has this option convert)

"Files should be saved with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding. The **BOM** should not be used."
[codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file_format](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file_format)